# Facebook WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder Ok button response

Tags: android, android-facebook

In my Facebook Application, I am sharing my post using FeedDialogBuilder.
I have a condition that, if I delete the app id from facebook account and try to share, then the following image displays. When I click on the "OK" button once,then the Web dialogue didn't dismiss. When I double click the same button, then dialogue box dismissed.

```
 public void publishFeedDialog(final Context context,
        FacebookApiModel shareMessageContant) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", shareMessageContant.getShareMessageName());
    params.putString("caption", shareMessageContant.getShareMessageTitle());
    params.putString("description",
            shareMessageContant.getShareMessageDescription());
    params.putString("link", shareMessageContant.getShareMessageLink());
    WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(
            (Activity) context, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    onCompleteErrorChecker(values, error, context);

                }
            }).build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
public void onCompleteErrorChecker(Bundle values, FacebookException error,
        Context context) {
    if (error == null) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    "Posted story, id: " + postId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context.getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
        Toast.makeText(
                context.getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(),
                "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(
                context.getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(),
                "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

How can i dismiss the web dialogue through single tap on the "OK" button or is there any alternative way to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check for Stream post URL security. sometime it may generate this issue while opening Fcebook WebDialog.

1. Please Go to Facebook Developer Console.
2. Choose your app.
3. Settings > Migration tab > Set "Stream post URL security" Switch to Off.

Check now.

It may solve your problem.

Comment: Actually the problem is, when i clicked on the "OK" button then the webdialogue box was not dismissed.